Handling Null Values in Serialization with ObjectMapper for the Same Class？
I looking for help in finding a solution for serializing objects with ObjectMapper. There are many similar questions online, but I haven't found one that completely matches my situation. The reason for this situation is due to two different external systems, and there are many such classes. Defining serialization methods individually for each one is a bit troublesome and risky. I need to serialize a class in two ways: ignore null value and not. Both of them are might be used, so I cannot choose just one directly.
Is there a way to control at method level whether to ignore null value?
For Example:
// @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class User {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    // When email is null,
    // sometimes the email must exist in the final string,
    // even if it is empty. Other times, I need it to be absent.
    String email;
    /// ===== omitted getter / setter =====

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new User().setAge(11).setName("Christian")));
    }
}

Is there a better approach than implementing serialization methods individually for each case?

You can use 2 instances of object mapper depending on usecase.
One with default settings, and second one that ignores nulls
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
 mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);


It might be considered the closest method to my goal.

However, if possible, I would still prefer to use the same instance that achieves the goal with different methods or parameters.
